# Python utf-8 conversion to cp1252

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, ansi, cp1252

I already have the code to iterate through all files in a deep file structure where all files are utf-8 and need to be converted to c1252 a.k.a. ANSI.

I need to achieve the same simple result as coverting the file in any serious text editor... why would there be any losses? Yes, some characters are standardly replaced by different ones: Šš=Šš Čč=Èè Ťť=?? Žž=Žž Ěě=Ìì Řř=Øø Ďď=Ïï Ňň=Òò Ůů=Ùù

But since a simple string conversion like

```
>>> print("Šš Čč Ťť Žž Ěě Řř Ďď Ňň Ůů".encode("utf-8").decode("cp1252"))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 15, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,errors,decoding_table)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 8: character maps to <undefined>
```

... doesn't work what are my chances? I've been literally through dozens of articles here and there throughout the whole day and could not find a working solution or understand the hell of this cp conversion PITA. Found even complete functions and converter obviously written for Python 2 none working.

Also not working:

`chcp 65001`

`Active code page: 65001`

```
           with open(fpath, mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as fd:
               content = fd.read()
           with open(fpath, mode="w", encoding="cp1252") as fd:
               fd.write(content)
```

or

```
          with open(fpath, mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as fd:
               decoded = fd.decode("utf-8")
               content = decoded.encode("cp1252")
```

Comment: About your first example: you can't encode text in an encoding system (utf-8) and decode using another (cp1252). What error occurs when trying the examples 2 and 3? Are you sure your files were wrote using utf-8?

Comment: Why would you want to replace Ř with Ø? This is certainly not any kind of "standard replacement", rather it's a data mistake – characters misinterpreted by guessing the encoding wrong.

Comment: `Řř=Øø` is an instantiated [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case: `'Řř'.encode( 'cp1250').decode( 'cp1252')` returns `'Øø'` @lenz …

Answer (score 0):

Your first example will never work.  Encoding a Unicode string using one scheme and decoding to another is incorrect, but you can *decode* a file or byte string using the encoding it was generated with, then *re-encode* it in another encoding.  The encodings need to support the same Unicode code points, however.

UTF-8 supports encoding all Unicode code points while [CP1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) supports <256, so don't expect your files to contain the same information if you go this route.

There is an `errors` parameter that can be used when decoding (reading) a file and encoding (writing) a file. Here's an example of the loss from the example string provided:

```py
>>> s = "Šš Čč Ťť Žž Ěě Řř Ďď Ňň Ůů"
>>> s.encode('cp1252',errors='ignore').decode('cp1252')
'Šš   Žž     '
>>> s.encode('cp1252',errors='replace').decode('cp1252')
'Šš ?? ?? Žž ?? ?? ?? ?? ??'
```

There are non-lossy conversions as well, but use replacement schemes.  See [Error Handlers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#error-handlers) in the Python [codecs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html) documentation.

So the second example can work with loss by providing the `errors` parameter:

```py
with open(fpath, mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as fd:
    content = fd.read()
with open(fpath, mode="w", encoding="cp1252", errors='replace') as fd:
    fd.write(content)
```

Comment: I need to achieve the same simple result as coverting the file in any serious text editor... why would there be any losses? Yes, some characters are standardly replaced by different ones:
Šš=Šš Čč=Èè Ťť=?? Žž=Žž Ěě=Ìì Řř=Øø Ďď=Ïï Ňň=Òò Ůů=Ùù
    
How to achieve this?

Comment: @MirekHotový CP1252 is a single-byte encoding, one byte == one Unicode code point.  There are only 256 values for a single byte.  There are 1M+ Unicode code points.  You can only save the supported Unicode code points in a CP1252-encoded file.  UTF-8 is a multibyte encoding that can support the entire range of Unicode codepoints.